# Update several post_meta data in one mySQL query

Tags: mysql

I want to perform some updates to posts' meta data in a WordPress site (wp_postmeta table).
The known good'ol function `update_post_meta()` is doing the job and also will check and if key not exist, it will add it.
But, this function can handle only one post at a time.
I want to save expensive db calls and update  with one query several fields for different post ids.

Generally, I could use mySQL `UPDATE` query with `CASE` to swich and assign each `meta_value` according to `post_id`, like [in this example](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/), and update some values of different rows in the table.
But, it may be that for some of the posts, that `meta_key` is not existing yet, so `INSERT` is needed and not update. Well, if not using the `update_post_meta()`, I should check this somehow. 
I tried to use `INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` ([syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)) and also `REPLACE` ([syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)), but it is relevant only for columns that are unique or defined as primary keys, so it doesn't help in this case.

Is there a way or an idea for how can I have the "Insert value, and update if already exists this meta_key for this post_id" and do this for several different post_ids (same meta_key however all the way), and with one single mySQL query?

Thanks
(* I asked this also in WordPress answers, and asking here too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`REPLACE` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` are *not* "relevant only for columns that are unique or defined as primary keys", rather the determination of whether the record is new or already existing (and thus needs to be replaced/updated) is made on whether there is a unique key collision or not.  As the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) states:

> MySQL uses the following algorithm for `REPLACE` (and `LOAD DATA ... REPLACE`):
>
> 1. Try to insert the new row into the table
> 2. While the insertion fails because a duplicate-key error occurs for a primary key or unique index:
>
>    a. Delete from the table the conflicting row that has the duplicate key value
>
>    b. Try again to insert the new row into the table

It describes `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` [similarly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Therefore, provided your `REPLACE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` command identifies your updated records by their current primary keys, it should do exactly what you wish.  According to the [WordPress documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), the primary key is the `meta_id` field, so with a `SELECT` you obtain this identifier for the existing cases and with an outer join, get `NULL` if it doesn't already exist (which [sets the column to the next `auto_increment` value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html)):

```
REPLACE INTO `wp_postmeta` (
      `meta_id`
    , `post_id`
    , `meta_key`
    , `meta_value`
)
    SELECT
          `meta_id`
        , `post_id`
        , "key of interest"
        , "new value" -- assuming all posts to be set the same
    FROM
        `wp_postmeta`
        NATURAL RIGHT JOIN (
           SELECT 1 AS `post_id` -- where 1 is the first post_id
           UNION SELECT 2        -- 2 is the second
           UNION SELECT 3        -- 3 is the third
           -- etc.
        ) AS `temp_table`
    WHERE
        `meta_id` IS NULL OR `meta_key` = "key of interest"
;
```

If the new meta value is to be different for each post, you could add such values as a second column in `temp_table`:

```
REPLACE INTO `wp_postmeta` (
      `meta_id`
    , `post_id`
    , `meta_key`
    , `meta_value`
)
    SELECT
          `meta_id`
        , `post_id`
        , "key of interest"
        , `new_value`
    FROM
        `wp_postmeta`
        NATURAL RIGHT JOIN (
           SELECT 1 AS `post_id`, "foo" AS `new_value`
           UNION SELECT 2, "bar"
           UNION SELECT 3, "qux"
           -- etc.
        ) AS `temp_table`
    WHERE
        `meta_id` IS NULL OR `meta_key` = "key of interest"
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very explained answer and query example! I will test this in the following days, I assume it will solve the issue.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It updates the rows, but insertion doesn't work as expected.